# How can I implement conditional exposure of a RepositoryRestResource?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I want to conditionally expose repositories annotated with RepositoryRestResource based on a Spring Boot application property which will have an environment-specific value.

I hoped to use something like `exported = "${myProperty}"` but only a literal true or false is accepted.

The only solution I am currently aware of is implementing a custom `RepositoryDetectionStrategy` instead.

Is there a simpler way that is similar to annotating a `@Bean` with `@ConditionalOnProperty`?

Comment: Have you tried using @ConditionalOnProperty with @RepositoryRestResource?

Comment: `@ConditionalOnProperty` will prevent the repository bean from being created if it does not match. I always want the repository to be created; I need to control whether it is is exported as a REST resource.

Comment: AFAIK, the only way is to implement a custom RepositoryDetectionStrategy.

Comment: @mahsum, this is what ended up doing and it's working well.